# jQuery how to reference an id that is an index

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I am trying to generate markup via jQuery with a loop which creates n many `div`s, each being assigned an `id` of the loop index. When I want to call a particular `div` by its `id` how do I concatonate the `#` with `i`? Thanks?

```
        for(int i=0; i<ListSize; i++) {
            $('<div></div>').attr('id', i).appendTo('#loadMe');

            // Help, how to reference an id that is an index?
            $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#'+i);    // This doesn't work.
            $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#'+i);     // This doesn't work.

        }
```

Comment: Warning: this technique will result in duplicate ids if it is ever used more than once in a page! And it's also not very clear what you're doing if you need to reference "#1" somewhere else in JavaScript or CSS.  I would suggest to prefix the index number with something more descriptive of what it actually is.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the advance. This is just a shorthand example however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the markup in the loop, change the DOM once :

```
var container = $([]);

$.each(ListSize, function(i) {
    var div  = $('<div />', {id : 'div' + i}),
        h1_1 = $('<h1 />', {text: firstName}),
        h1_2 = $('<h1 />', {text: lastName});

    container = container.add( div.append(h1_1, h1_2) );
});

$('#loadMe').append( container );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5JbPz/)

Comment: It turns out my script works, however I really like this^!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this you can do this like:

```
for(int i=0; i<ListSize; i++) {
    //this would create the DOM element with the index as its id
    var iDiv = $('<div id=' + i + '></div>');

    $('<h1>' + firstName + '</h1>').appendTo(iDiv);
    $('<h1>' + lastName + '</h1>').appendTo(iDiv);

    //I usually prefer create the all DOM elements I want then append it to 
    iDiv.appendTo('#loadMe');
}
```

And you can also create the whole DOM elements in one line code:

```
for(int i=0; i<ListSize; i++) {
    var iDiv = $('<div id=' + i + '><h1>' + firstName + '</h1><h1>' + lastName + '</h1></div>').appendTo('#loadMe');
}
```

but if you insist on using the IDs you can do what you want like:

```
for(int i=0; i<ListSize; i++) {
    $('<div></div>').attr('id', i).appendTo('#loadMe');

    $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo($('#loadMe').find('#'+i));
    $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo($('#loadMe').find('#'+i));

}
```

Comment: If it works you should leave out the comments that state otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, but change `int` to `var`.

```
for(var i=0; i<ListSize; i++) {
    var iDiv = $('<div id=' + i + '></div>');
    iDiv.appendTo('#loadMe');

    $('<h1>' + firstName + '</h1>').appendTo(iDiv);
    $('<h1>' + lastName + '</h1>').appendTo(iDiv);

}
```

Here is the live demo. http://jsfiddle.net/Ez7ZH/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest prefixing your IDs with at least one letter. Aside from being a semantic improvement, IDs beginning with numbers are only valid as of HTML5 (see [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for further details).